# Initial launch of installed software

Tags: software-installation, google-earth

[Google Earth was installed using this procedure on 16.10.](https://skagitsignal.com/how-to-install-google-earth-64-bit-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts-x64/)   What is the file to invoke from the command line to launch the application?

[image]

## UPDATE

Found a script that should be used to invoke the application:

user@hostname:/opt/google/earth/pro$ google-earth-pro

```
#!/bin/sh
# Always run Google Earth from this shell script and not
# Google Earth directly! This script makes sure the app looks
# in the right place for libraries that might also be installed
# elsewhere on your system.
#
# Ryan C. Gordon,  Thu Jul 20 14:32:33 PDT 2006

# Function to find the real directory a program resides in.
FindPath()
{
    fullpath="`echo $1 | grep /`"
    if [ "$fullpath" = "" ]; then
        oIFS="$IFS"
        IFS=:
        for path in $PATH
        do if [ -x "$path/$1" ]; then
               if [ "$path" = "" ]; then
                   path="."
               fi
               fullpath="$path/$1"
               break
           fi
        done
        IFS="$oIFS"
    fi
    if [ "$fullpath" = "" ]; then
        fullpath="$1"
    fi

    # Is the sed/ls magic portable?
    if [ -L "$fullpath" ]; then
        #fullpath="`ls -l "$fullpath" | awk '{print $11}'`"
        fullpath=`ls -l "$fullpath" |sed -e 's/.* -> //' |sed -e 's/\*//'`
    fi
    dirname $fullpath
}

script_path=$(FindPath $0);

cd $script_path;

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ./googleearth-bin "$@"
```

Comment: BTW There would have been a much simpler procedure to install Google Earth: go to [this site](https://www.google.com/earth/download/gep/agree.html), choose the 64bit version and when asked select 'open with software manager'. There you only have to click on `install`.

Comment: @muclux: Where you able to install GE without downloading and installing the 3 packages as prescribed in the procedure?

Comment: Yes. After seeing your post, I went to the site indicated in my comment above, and chose to open the downloaded file with software manager to install it. I have Ubuntu 17.10 - if that makes a difference?

Comment: @muclux: thanks.  The procedure I posted is the superset of (includes) your procedure and is the final step (both reference the same Google link).  Perhaps 17.10 has the first three packages already baked-in and enables a direct download and install.   Did it install it to /opt/google/earth/pro?  Unfortunately, the results after invoking the app is buggy.

Comment: Yes, it is in /opt/google/earth/pro.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to find Google Earth executable by listing all installed files and searching here its executable or desktop file.

I do not have Google Earth Pro installation, so here are examples for normal version:

- list all installed files and find placed in *bin* here:

  ```
  $ dpkg -L google-earth-stable | grep bin/
  /usr/bin/google-earth
  $ file /usr/bin/google-earth
  /usr/bin/google-earth: symbolic link to /opt/google/earth/free/googleearth
  ```

  so Google Earth executable is located in *`/usr/bin/google-earth`* and it is a symbolic link to *`/opt/google/earth/free/googleearth`*.
- search desktop file and show *Exec* line:

  ```
  $ dpkg -L google-earth-stable | grep desktop
  $ /opt/google/earth/free/google-earth.desktop
  $ cat /opt/google/earth/free/google-earth.desktop | grep Exec
  Exec=/opt/google/earth/free/google-earth %f
  ```

  so executable file is located in *`/opt/google/earth/free/google-earth`*.

I'm using MATE DE, so I can find Google Earth icon in the menu *Applications|Internet|Google Earth* - it is the most user-friendly solution.

Comment: `cat $(dpkg -L google-earth-stable | grep desktop) | grep Exec` if you want a one liner.

Comment: or (before someone yells at me): `grep Exec $(dpkg -L google-earth-stable | grep desktop)` to prevent the useless use of cat.

Answer (score 0):

By default google earth is installed here

> /usr/local/bin/googleearth

You should be able to launch it just by putting the path into Terminal.

---

Alternatively, if google earth was installed to a nonstandard location you could use the find tool to locate it via the Terminal.

```
find / -name googleearth 2>/dev/null
```

This will search the entire system for a file named googleearth.

Comment: Better use `find / -name googleearth 2>/dev/null` to avoid all the error messages for directories you are not allowed to read (and where googleearth will not be located).

Comment: Very true, I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: It is not universal solution. It is dirty bruteforce hack and it is slow. Software was installed with APT, so it registered its files in /var/lib/dpkg/database. User can search its contents with standard dpkg utility.

Answer (score 0):

You also can find it in the GUI: click on `Show Applications` (in 17.10 at the bottom of the Dashboard, in former version at the top) and begin typing `google earth`. While typing you should see Google Earth. While it is running, it appears with its icon in the Dashboard and you may pin it if you want to use it more often (right click on the icon and `add to favorites`).

Comment: OP wants to find its executable.

Comment: This response correctly anticipates the next step after finding the executable and pinning a shortcut to the taskbar